# Get annotations for enum type variable

Tags: java, reflection, enums, annotations

I have some non`null` variable (e.g. `en1`) of [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) type. The question is: how to get annotations related to enumeration constant referenced by `en1` variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Is it `Object en1 = ...; Annotation[] anns = magic(en1);`? Then I'd ask why `en1` is of type `Object` and not `En`. Could you provide some sample code like that?

Comment: I've found the right answer. It is: `en1.getClass().getField(((Enum)en1).name()).getAnnotations();`

Comment: @musiKk: I'm sorry. My statement *“`en1` of some `enum` type”* means that `en1` is instance of `Enum`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As I've already offered:

```
en1.getClass().getField(((Enum)en1).name()).getAnnotations();
```

To be clearer:

```
String name = e.name(); // Enum method to get name of presented enum constant
Annotation[] annos = e.getClass().getField(name).getAnnotations(); // Classical reflection technique
```

In this case we have no need to know real class of `en1`.

See also: [remark about obfuscated case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39298747/274205).

Comment: looks like the same answer from 8 hours prior

Answer (score 40):

Try this (java reflection):

```
String field = En.AAA.name();
En.class.getField(field).getAnnotations();
```

It should get you the annotations from `AAA`.

EDIT:

As the author supposed:

```
en1.getClass().getField(((Enum)en1).name()).getAnnotations();
```

Works for him :)

Comment: Using `.name()` would be safer than using `.toString()`, since `toString()` might be overloaded (while `name()` is `final`).

Comment: Your answer is not complete, because I do not know for sure which of the `En` constants assigned to `en1`. And furthermore I've edited my question just before your answer, applying more strict requirements.

Comment: But it doesn't work, does it? It seems an empty array is always returned. And `isAnnotationPresent()` always returns `false`

Comment: @rds - make sure you're using `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` on your `@interface`.

Answer (score 7):

I just read from your comment that you already found the answer. I just wanted to remark for other people interested that, in order for that to work, those annotations must have been declared with the correct retention policy, like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Anno1 {
   // ...
}
```

Without this, they will not be accessible at runtime.

Further reading:

- [JavaDoc: RetentionPolicy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html)
- [Wikipedia: Java annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation)

Comment: Also it should be noticed that if the `@Target` annotation presented there should be at least `ElementType.FIELD` in it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an obfuscator such as Proguard, you might find that the enum fields have been renamed, while `.name()` still returns the original name of the field. For example, this enum...

```
enum En {
    FOO,
    BAR
}
```

...would become this after ProGuarding...

```
enum En {
    a,
    b
}
```

...but `En.FOO.name()` will still return `"FOO"`, causing `getField(En.FOO.name())` to fail because it expects the field to be named `"a"`.

If you want to get the `Field` for a specific enum field from obfuscated code, you can do this:

```
for (Field field : En.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (field.isEnumConstant()) {
        try {
            if (en1 == field.get(null)) {
                Annotation[] annotations = field.getAnnotations();
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to the existing answers, if you are in control of the enum class (can edit it), you could simply add a method to the enum to fetch the required annotation i.e.

```
AnnotationClass getAnnotation(){
   Field field = this.getClass().getField(this.name());
   return field.getAnnotation(AnnotationClass.class);       
}
```

or all it's annotations:

```
Annotation[] getAnnotations(){
   Field field = this.getClass().getField(this.name());
   return field.getAnnotations();
}
```

Adjust the code above to handle exceptions (NoSuchFieldException and  SecurityException).